# How update style layer weight with Array values

Tags: javascript, leaflet

how I can update the values ​​of weights of layers by multiplying each element of my array `Array = [2,4,5,5,1,9,9,1,1]` with a fixed value =3

```
Array = [2,4,5,5,1,9,9,1,1]

    list_layer[1].eachLayer(function(layer) {
        layer.setStyle({
          opacity: 0.3,
          weight: 3,
        });
      });
```

eg:
for first Layer :

```
list_layer[1].eachLayer(function(layer) {
        layer.setStyle({
          opacity: 0.3,
          weight: 3 * Array[0],
        });
      });
```

for second : `weight: 3 * Array[1],`

Comment: Depends on the structure of `list_layer`. More info is needed.

Comment: ```list_layer``` is a list that includes ```L.layerGroup();```  eg : ```list_layer = [L1, L2]``` where ```L1``` and ```L2``` is ```L.layerGroup();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used leaflet, but reading the documentation, it looks like the eachLayer callback doesn't accept an index.

But I think you could do something like this:

```
let i = 0;
list_layer[1].eachLayer(function(layer) {
   layer.setStyle({
      opacity: 0.3,
      weight: 3 * Array[i],
   });
   i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a index to your loop:

```
var i = 0;
list_layer[1].eachLayer(function(layer) {
        layer.setStyle({
          opacity: 0.3,
          weight: 3 * Array[i],
        });
        i++;
      });
```